# Datagrid view, pass column value to stored procedure on doubleclick

Tags: c#, variables, datagridview

in the process of learning C# so apologies if this is nonsense..

I have two forms at the moment, one with a datagridview, another that will be populated with data from a stored procedure.

My problem is I need to pass the variable into my stored procedure as a parameter and I'm not entire sure how I would go about doing that.

Here is my code so far:

```
        public void dgvRiskAssess_CellContentDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedRow = dgvRiskAssess.SelectedRows[0];
        var primaryKey = selectedRow.Cells["Assessment ID"].Value;


        frmDetails detailsForm = new frmDetails();
        detailsForm.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the frmDetails shows the results of the stored proc, there are 2 options:

Option #1:

1. pass the value of "primaryKey" to frmDetails: to do this, just declare a public property on frmDetails and set it after

frmDetails detailsForm = new frmDetails();

1. implement the form_load event of frmOptions to get the stored proc data and display it.

option #2:

1. get the stored proc data in your existing form containing the above data grid view.
2. once you get the stored proc data (e.g. AssessmentDetails object), have a public property on the frmDetails form and set it after

frmDetails detailsForm = new frmDetails();

1. implement form_load event and display this data. (you can also display this data on the setter of the property)